# Pygame game error with bullets and Math module

Tags: python, math, pygame, valueerror, topdown

I have been making a game that uses Pygame and Math. It is a top-down shooter. Right now, I only have scrolling movement and (broken) bullets. When I try to fire a bullet by clicking on any place on the screen, I get an error message with this.

```
  File "/home/radioactivethirst/PyCode/zombiesurvival.py", line 55, in <module>
    pistol_bullets.append(PistolBullet(player.x, player.y, mouse_x, mouse_y))
  File "/home/radioactivethirst/PyCode/zombiesurvival.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.x_vel = math.sin(self.angle) * self.speed
TypeError: must be real number, not tuple
```

The bullets are supposed to move constantly toward where the mouse is pointing at the time the mouse is clicked.
Attached is a link to my program.

https://pastebin.com/XC5BzJ89

Thank you :)

Comment: You have to add the code to the question links to external resources tend to break or the content may change.

Answer (score -1):

You wrote

```
self.angle = math,atan2(y-mouse_y, x-mouse_x)
```

Then you had a debugging problem and you never printed out `self.angle` before asking StackOverflow.

Rather than storing a 2-tuple of the `math` module followed by the desired arctangent FP value, it would be better to call `math.atan2( ... )` and store its result.
To clarify, `,` comma is used to separate tuple elements,
while `.` dot is used when referring to elements of an object,
such as functions within the math module.

Please read: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs

---

Get the [flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) linter, and use it.
Linting would have complained about
`E231 missing whitespace after ','`
and then the typo would have been more apparent.
Everyone makes mistakes.
Make enough of them and you'll look for ways
to avoid repeat mistakes.
Using a linter is one good way to avoid making yet another typo or foolish error.
The machine is offering you help -- why refuse it?